# Kaggle output path has invalid characters

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, kaggle

I am trying to publish an R notebook on Kaggle.
Most of the notebook are ggplots plots.
It works fine (no warning) until I press publish.

The page reloads... and I get my notebook in a very weird layout:
https://postimg.org/image/fmb8dswa7/

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After importing the notebook block by block I found the problem.
In order to have an interactive index I used Markdown like so :
In the index :

```
- [Title...](#id-section0)
```

Further down :

```
<div id='id-section0'/>
# Title...
```

It worked fine on my local machine but not when Kaggle was rendering HTML. After deleting those headers, it worked fine